# <Java> Chess pawn movement issue

Tags: java, chess

i'm making a chess game in java, and pawns are giving me a hell of a problem. I honestly don't know why, as their movement is the simplest. Here's the Piece declaration, and the Pawn (extends Piece) declaration. The movement class defines a simple x;y object that i use to mark possible movement targets on the board.. i have a GameHandler class that later depures all impossible movements based on game rules later. But Pawn's moves array seems to be clean; all other pieces' movements work like wonders! Thanks in advance!

Piece class

```
public abstract class Piece{
    protected int x, y;
    protected boolean isWhite;
    protected ArrayList<Movement> moves;
    public Piece(int x, int y, boolean isWhite) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.isWhite = isWhite;
        moves = new ArrayList<Movement>();
    }
    public abstract ArrayList<Movement> getMoves();
    //obvious methods
    public int getX()
    public int getY()
    public boolean isWhite()
    //end obvious methods
    public void setCoordinates(int x, int y){
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }   
}
```

Pawn class

```
public class Pawn extends Piece{
    public Pawn(int x, int y, boolean isWhite){
        super(x,y,isWhite);
    }
    public ArrayList<Movement> getMoves() {
        moves.clear();
        if(isWhite){
            if(y>0) moves.add(new Movement(x, y-1));
            if(y==7) moves.add(new Movement(x, y-2));
        }else{
            if(y<7) moves.add(new Movement(x, y+1));
            if(y==0) moves.add(new Movement(x, y+2));
        }
        return moves;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding King class as reference

```
public class King extends Piece{
    public King(int x, int y, boolean isWhite){
        super(x,y,isWhite);
    }
    public ArrayList<Movement> getMoves() {
        moves.clear();
        if(y-1>=0 && x-1>=0) moves.add(new Movement (x-1, y-1));
        if(y-1>=0 && x+1<8) moves.add(new Movement (x+1, y-1));
        if(y+1<8 && x+1<8) moves.add(new Movement (x+1, y+1));
        if(y+1<8 && x-1>=0) moves.add(new Movement (x-1, y+1));
        if(y-1>=0) moves.add(new Movement (x, y-1));
        if(y+1<8) moves.add(new Movement (x, y+1));
        if(x+1<8) moves.add(new Movement (x+1, y));
        if(x-1>=0) moves.add(new Movement (x-1, y));
        return moves;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly how you are numbering your ranks, but it sounds like you want to check for `y == 6` and `y == 1` instead of 7 and 0, since pawns start ahead of the other pieces.

Comment: Do you have any other game pieces that you could post that are working?

Comment: Pawn is hardly the simplest one. It can start with a double-move, it can turn into queens. Much more complex than a bishop, for example.

Comment: It can also attack on diagonals

Comment: and is subject to [en passant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant) rules

Comment: Oh sorry.. the GameHandler class has a Piece[8][8] where i place the pieces, and a GUI class that has a 8x8 grid with JButtons replicating the Piece matrix. Btw.. think you are right about the y==6 & y==1.. but it still didn't fix the problem

Comment: yes yes, but i still can't make it even go straight! I'll later work around other movements. @djc391 king class added as reference

Comment: so X = {a, ..., h} and Y = {1, ..., 8} on the real board, i am correct?

Comment: > But Pawn's moves array seems to be clean; Do you mean it is empty?

Comment: It's supposed to be cleaned of movements each time the method is called, so it can refill the "moves" array with the new movements for the new pawn position. And X = {a, .. , h} as you said

Comment: What is the code for the initialization of a `Pawn` (where the moves end up to be clean)?

Comment: you mean the "moves = new ArrayList<Movement>();" ?

Comment: @Iñaki Guastalli, I mean, what are `x` `y` `isWhite` where you actually use the class.

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek ah! x & y are the piece's (pawn in this case) location within a Piece[][], and the isWhite indicates.. well, if the piece is white or not, to settle the direction of it's movements. They are all three initialized in the Piece constructor, as you can see.. I later label JButtons wPawn or bPawn according to the isWhite value, so it DEFINITELY is white for white pawns and viceversa.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a bug in this line:

```
if(isWhite){
        if(y>0) moves.add(new Movement(x, y-1));
        ...
```

Should be:

```
if(!isWhite) {
   if(y> ...
```

(So that Black, not White pawn's rank decreases when it moves forward).

As was already noted, pawn moves are the most difficult to code - it can move 2 squares forward from the starting position (but only if there is no other piece in front), it captures diagonally, it can promote to one of the 4 other piece types. Also, consider this position:

[image: Chess diagram]

Here (assuming White is to move) White pawn has no legal moves at all, as it is pinned by the Black Bishop. However, if the last move by Black was c7-c5, then the White pawn can capture the Black pawn and move to c6 (["En passant" rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/En_passant)).

You could improve readability of your code by renaming `x` and `y` as `file` and `rank`, respectively. I would also consider introducing an

```
enum PieceColour {
   WHITE, BLACK
}
```

and using `PieceColour pieceColour` and `if (pieceColour == PieceColour.BLACK)` instead of `boolean isWhite` and `if(!isWhite)`.

Comment: that's some interesting thoughts.. i'm currently coding the en passant for the pawns, but i'm yet to code the checkmate conditions.
Also, this is one of my first works in Java, first time learning objects' programming in collage, and there's further we don't have time to cover; so i'll have to read some about that "enum" class, interface, structure, object,.. something, before i can use it (and understand what it is haaha) thanks for all the help btw!

Answer (score 1):

Okay one idea.

Take a look at your if statement.

Try

```
if(this.isWhite)
```

or

```
if(isWhite())
```

Also for a chess board I think you should be checking if position is equal to 1, or 6. Not 0 or 7.

Comment: Already fixed! True on the 1-6 positions..
Also, the problem was that i was checking in columns instead of rows on pawns.. as pawns are the only pieces that move in a fixed direction it needed to be harderly defined.. and i misdefined it hahahah it kept giving me no available moves as it was checking for empty positions on the sides of the pawn, instead of on the front: should compare on x instead of y